# Creating a dictionary object column from two other columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have this dataframe

```
data = {'Name': ["Bob", "Mike"],
       'Age': ['32', '31'],
       'Value': ['123.123', '124.56']}
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df_test.head()
```

I want to create dictionary like this for each row

```
{'Age': '32',
'Value': '123.123'}
```

Such that I would get this

```
data = {'Name': ["Bob", "Mike"],
       'Age': ['32', '31'],
       'Value': ['123.123', '124.56'],
        'parameters': [{'Age': '32', 'Value': '123,123'}, {'Age': 31, 'Value': '124.56'}]}
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df_test.head()
```

How would I do this? I thought of creating a function and then just using .apply() but I am not exactly sure how to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with parameter `orient='records'`:

```
df_test['parameters'] = df_test[['Age','Value']].to_dict(orient='records')
print (df_test)
   Name Age    Value                         parameters
0   Bob  32  123.123  {'Age': '32', 'Value': '123.123'}
1  Mike  31   124.56   {'Age': '31', 'Value': '124.56'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `orient='index'`:

```
df_test['parameters'] = pd.Series(df_test.drop(columns='Name').to_dict('index'))
```

output:

```
   Name Age    Value                         parameters
0   Bob  32  123.123  {'Age': '32', 'Value': '123.123'}
1  Mike  31   124.56   {'Age': '31', 'Value': '124.56'}
```